# Printing failure at a network printer in linux

Tags: linux, networking, rhel, printing

I added a network printer to my network by the RedHat Enterprise workstation 6 linux GUI. It seemed that the printer setting did find the network printer. However, whenever I tried to print, the job didn't go through. I typed command such as

```
lpstat -t
```

And the results showed as

```
scheduler is running
system default destination: HP-Color-LaserJet-cp2025dn
device for HP-Color-LaserJet-cp2025dn: lpd://10.242.25.238/10.242.15.238
HP-Color-LaserJet-cp2025dn accepting requests since Fri 08 Jun 2012 04:03:30 PM EDT
printer HP-Color-LaserJet-cp2025dn now printing HP-Color-LaserJet-cp2025dn-0.  enabled since Fri 08 Jun 2012 04:03:30 PM EDT
    Connecting to printer...
HP-Color-LaserJet-cp2025dn-8 Cassie               1024   Fri 08 Jun 2012 04:03:30 PM EDT
```

Doesn't it mean the linux system detect the network printer already ? However, I still got some status message such as

```
Printer 'HP-Color-LaserJet-cp2025dn' may not be connected.
```

And all the printing jobs were pending and never went through at all. I have to cancel all printing jobs on my linux.

I checked the physical connection of my network printer and it seemed fine.
Any idea where to check if the network printer connection is good, if my linux detects it and why the printing jobs always fails ? Thank you very much,

Comment: That's an odd queue name, usually they're `lpd://ipaddress/PRINTER_NAME`.  Also, accepting and enabled refer to the CUPS server.  It doesn't reflect the actual printer status.

Comment: Yes, with network printers it's worth noting that there is a printer server running on the printer, and there's your usual CUPS server running locally. When you print, there *is* a connected printer, which gets the printing job, but that printer is a printer in the local CUPS server that will then *try* to send the job to the remote printer. It probably fails to connect to the remote printer and stops processing jobs. (There is indeed the possibility your local CUPS server is not correctly configured for that remote printer.)

Comment: May I ask further how I should configure my CUPS server ? Thanks